# How to stop selenium webdriver from waiting for page load?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, pageload

Sometimes when i run a test, website never stops loading and my test stucks on it. How can i set driver.get() method to not wait for page load? If its impossible are there any work arounds or other methods that could replace driver.get()?

Comment: The first question you should ask yourself is why your website doesn't stop loading?

Comment: How are you going to test a site that never stops loading?

Comment: It's not my website and i dont need it fully loaded, i just need several controls/buttons to load.

Comment: If site loading slow it self then no control / method of selenium can help to solve issue..have to wait till site loads.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to exit the page load wait early is to set the page load timeout. When the timeout expires, you can catch the `TimeoutException` and proceed with the next step of your test. The code to invoke this would look something like the following:

```
// Set the page load timeout to 10 seconds.
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

try {
  driver.get("http://url/to/my/slow/loading/page");
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
  // Ignore the exception.
}

// Proceed with your next step here.
```

Note that you may have to use a `WebDriverWait` or similar to ensure the element you're interested in is present on the page.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It keeps waiting for the page complete loading to execute the next command.

Answer (score 0):

We can set pageLoadTimeout, once set it wil be there throught the webdriver session, and if the exception is thrown because of timeout then we can't restore same session so need to create new instance.

```
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //waits 10 seconds for page to load
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        try {
            driver.get("https://yourdomain.com");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();

            //create new instance of webdriver
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            //waits 5 minutes for page to load
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://yourdomain.com");
        }
```